# Express server large post (>3gb) endpoint error

Tags: express, body-parser

My express server can't take POST request larger than 2GB.

I have tried expanding the buffer size of body parser, it has not worked. I have tried expanding the heap size, it has not worked.

This is the error message:

```
buffer.js:262
    throw err;
    ^

RangeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "3228869136" is invalid for option "size"
    at Function.allocUnsafe (buffer.js:284:3)
    at Function.concat (buffer.js:463:25)
    at getBuffer (/home/minjae/Dev/mednick_minjae/mednick_api_minjae/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/memHandler.js:16:34)
    at FileStream.file.on (/home/minjae/Dev/mednick_minjae/mednick_api_minjae/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/processMultipart.js:58:19)
    at FileStream.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at FileStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:481:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1139:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
```

It emits error even before it gets to the first code after my endpoint, so I guess it came from a middleware such as body-parser, but I can't fix it.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of parser you are using? url-encoded or text or raw?

Comment: I use body-parser module of npm, json format. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser  I was wondering if the buffer size of this parser is not large enough.

Comment: You tried increasing https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#limit?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did. It still didn't work.

Comment: The filesize restriction of the Node V8 engine is 2GB. So it is (not yet) possible to manage Buffers larger as 2 GB for x64 systems. (1GB for x86 systems)

There is no way to bypass this.

Comment: Are you uploading a file? I think for you problem do you need use `multer` https://github.com/expressjs/multer for `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Thanks for answers, the problem was Express-Fileupload module. I was able to fix error by adding "useTempFiles: true" option to the configuration. It previously stores all the data at the heap and it breaks when the data is too large for the heap. "useTempFiles" option makes a temporary file and store incoming data there, just like what happens when we download something from the internet. (in this case, client uploads and server downloads)